# Using Osmosis to create small database

Tags: php, xml, openstreetmap

I read a lot about planet files, osmosis and stuff. What i try do do is create a small mysql database which contains some basic georeference data of locations. Something like this:

```
loc_id | loc_name | lat    | long  | level | level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | level5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123    | germany  | 1.1234 | 1.1234| 2     | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0
5881   | berlin   | 1.1234 | 1.1234| 3     | 1      | 123    | 5881   | 0      | 0
123123 | kreuzberg| 1.1234 | 1.1234| 4     | 1      | 5881   | 5881   | 123123 | 0
```

I guess you get the idea. You can ignore the demo coordinates. What i need is a start on how to get this simple structure out of a osm file. I guess its not that easy. Especialy when trying to create that level data. I read that you can use osmosis pipes to arrange that, but i just need a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`osm2pgsql`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) for getting a postgis database containing this information.
The good thing is that Postgis supports various operations to do calculations with your data.